# Android issue in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android, flutter-doctor

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip'.
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\src\App\Nimmadhi\android/gradlew.bat''
Could not start 'C:\src\App\Nimmadhi\android/gradlew.bat'
Cannot run program "C:\src\App\Nimmadhi\android/gradlew.bat" (in directory "C:\src\App\Nimmadhi\android"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

After building my flutter project it shows this error message in my vs code terminal.
My flutter doctor shows no error and my java is working fine.

My github repo link: https://github.com/Nikil2580/Nimmadhi.git

Answer (score -1):

This error appears for you because you are using differents drives for work with flutter.

In your case u are using D and C.

Move all to same drive location .

And make a flutter clean.

Comment: I moved all files to the same location but the problem still persist.

Comment: what the New Error string?

Comment: I have posted it above

Comment: Your gradle path is incorret. Has gradle in C:\src\App\Nimmadhi\android/ ?